# Where can I put an included ExtendScript so it doesnt show on the menu?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

I have a script for Photoshop (jsx) that includes a utility script (jsx).  I don't want the utility script to be directly invokable from the Scripts menu.

Where can i put it  (on OSX and Windows both) so that it can be included by my visible script but not be visible itself on the menu?

Answer (score 1):

As an FYI - if you put it in a subfolder with the ending 'Scripts Only' it also gets hidden.  I use this to keep the scripts folder more organised rather than just throwing a bunch of inc files in with the main script files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The menu only includes scripts with a ".jsx" ending.  By changing my utility script to be ".inc" for its ending it did not show up in the menues but was still includable in my other script.